# after form submit in jQuery completed in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a php file and it contains a textfiled and submit button and a div and below is code

Page1.php

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="submit_class">

  <div class="suc_box">You have Entered</div>
</form>

if($_POST['submit']) {
  $v1 = $_POST['email1'];

  // $query1 =  here some code to insert into database

  if($query1 > 0){
    //here i want to display the div `suc_box`.. Here how i can show that div
  }
}
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('suc_box').hide();

    $('suc_box').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Question: How can I show/display that `suc_box` when form is submitted after it inserted into database?

Comment: Thanks for showing the code, but what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily with AJAX. You have one php-file with the form and another one for processing the data:

**//form_file.php**

```
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="validateform();">
  <input type="text" name="email1" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>

<div class="suc_box"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.suc_box').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('#my_form').submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('process.php',data,function(return_data){
      $('.suc_box').html(return_data);          
    });
    return false; //cancel the 'real' submit
  });
});   
</script>
```

**//process.php**

```
<?php
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
//write data to DB
if($succeeded) {
  echo 'You have Entered';
} else {
  echo 'Something went wrong, try again!';
}
```

It's untested, but you get the idea.

validating email field

```
    function validateform(){
        if (!/^\S+@\S+\.\w+$/.test(document.sweetform.Email.value)) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its now working `$('.suc_box').html(return_data);` not returning any data from `process.php`

Comment: @Rafee please make sure div is not hidden or something. You can easily debug with FireBug (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) - have a look at the HTML-tab (if the text is there) and especially the Console-tab while posting (to see what data is posted and if there were errors). Or use `alert(return_data);` to see if something is being returned. If really nothing is returned, make sure you have set the right path and filename to `process.php` (in this example, both files must me in the same directory).

Comment: actually this is email field and even i want to make it validating email.. and updating the code before it sends

Comment: And if the validation is false, then message div also displaying `You have Entered`

Comment: @Rafee You can (or should I say: MUST) validate it on the server side, which is in `process.php`, before inserting into database. Everything you `echo` out in `process.php` will be returned to `form_file.php` and be accessible via the `return_data`-variable within your postback-function. So do your validation and then echo whatever you want under whatevere conditions you want.

Comment: @Rafee The edit-function is meant to make small changes like fixing formatting or some typos, but not to add a bunch of content the original author has nothing to do with. Please mark it somehow as your own addition with a short comment or place it within your question instead. Since there's my name under this answer, I'm responsible for its content. And I don't know what your code does or how it's related to the rest of my answer - so I don't take the responsiblity :)

Comment: And one more thing: It's not enough to validate inputs on the client side only (i.e. with JavaScript). Post-data can easily be manipulated while posting. So make sure to also validate it on the server side (which is even more important!).

Answer (score 0):

If ive got you right you could do this however I would suggest looking into ajax to do what you want

```
    <div class="suc_box">
         You have Entered
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php  
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
     $v1 = $_POST['email1'];

     // $query1 =  here some code to insert into database

      if($query1 > 0){
       ?>


       <script type="text/javascript">
          $('suc_box').show();

       </script>
<?php
    }

    }
?>
```